# Clustering driven by an enum/list

Tags: algorithm, clustering

Given a set of 2D points ( or vertices if you want ), the values stored for each point are:

- coordinate on x
- coordinate on y
- an *enum* or a value from a list in general

for the sake of this example let's say that this last value is the name of a fruit, so the record in the data structure for each point looks like

```
"34.3" "845.2" "apple"
```

The set of fruits considered is finite and well defined at the moment the algorithm comes in to play, with this I mean that I can easily list all the possible variations for that 3rd value, if I need to.

Since in my model that 3rd value is assigned per-face, I don't really care if my algorithm acts on faces or on vertices; I should also note that the number of vertices for each face are not equals, so with the term "face" I mean a generic geometry that can be a triangle, a quad, and so on, but no matter how many vertices a face owns, the property is given per-face.

Now the real problem: **I need to do some clustering based on that 3rd arbitrary value**.

I don't have any pattern here, I have no guarantee on anything, for what I know it's possible to have the entire map composed of single faces with a different 3rd value, they can be convex or concave, the only thing is, I have this kind of records in input, and as output I need a set of areas grouped according to this 3rd value that they have in common.
Offcourse if 2 faces share the same 3rd value but they are not adjacent ( don't share at least 1 edge/verts ) they should be considered as 2 separated areas.

What is an algorithm for this kind of clustering ?

Since the dataset is relatively small the time-complexity of the algorithm doesn't really matters that much.

PS
If needed I can simplify every face down to a triangle; I am also not sure if this problem can be solved with a Convex Hull algorithm.